# delay in taking of input in code-blocks console

Tags: c, codeblocks

i am using dell-3460, core i5, 4GB Ram.OS win 8 And code blocks 13.2. My problem is that after writing any code when the "build and run" pressing the IDE console is appearing without any delay but the input option is coming at least after 25 second. what is the reason?

let consider this small fragment of code where it will take input in main in an array and send them into a function avg and there average will be printed there. but it is making delay of 30 second for taking input in my machine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void avg(double *Ar,int totalNum);
main()
{
    double numArray[3];
    int i=0;
    printf("Put the Number:\n");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    { 
        scanf("%lf",&numArray[i]);
    }
    printf("The Number Entered:\n");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%f",numArray[i]);
    }
    avg(numArray,3);
}
void avg(double *Ar,int totalNum)
{
    double total=0;
    int i;
    printf("\nThe Number Came here in AVG:\n");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        total+=Ar[i];
        printf("\n%f",Ar[i]);
    }
    printf("\nAvg:%f",(total/totalNum));
}
```

Comment: Note related to your issue `int main()` and `return 0` should be there in your code

Comment: Well , its something wrong with your PC or Your compiler as it had no such problem on mine. Try closing your program and try again

Comment: @gopi actually as small code for that skipped .

Comment: i also not been xperiencing with that, after giving the OS again it is happening. I tried by closing the program, even restarting the  machine.@ Arun A.S

Comment: Did this start to happen when you started using code blocks?

Comment: Then I suspect its got something to do with your compiler. I ran this code perfectly on mine with no delay at all. Have you ever experienced such problems before

Comment: No, it was not happening from start, but for few days. code blocks was installed for last 3-4 months. @Cool Guy

Comment: i xperienced this kind of problem before but after giving the OS again it was solved. But thinking giving OS again not be a solution. i should know the reason. @ Arun A.S

Comment: See if you are experiencing the same problem for any other simple code, and if you can , run this program with cin and cout ( since you are on codeblocks, they should work as well and hope you know how to use  them  ) instead of scanf and printf. If you can think of any other way to do input and output operations, then try that as well.

Comment: @Black Swan , I don't quite understand what you mean by " giving the OS again " . If you can please elaborate it. I want to know what you mean by that.

Comment: sorry,i am only know  C, not C++, as my knowledge cin and cout related with C++ @Arun A.S

Comment: Do you know of any other method to take input and show output, if you do know, then try it.

Comment: Forgot to ask, which OS are you using ( not that it would be of any use ).

Comment: ohh..i forget to tell windows 8. @Arun A.S

Comment: Is your code blocks suited for windows 8 ????

Comment: i also encountered such problem with some win 7 machine in my university lab ..@ Arun A.S